# ProcessStartInfo Verb runas?

Tags: c#, process, command

I cant find the methode in the class, furthermore the methode password is now PasswordInClearText are they any changelogs or anything?

How can i run a process in admin mode now?
this didnt worked-->

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
procStartInfo.UserName = "Memyself";
procStartInfo.PasswordInClearText = "password";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your TargetFramework to version of .NET Framework
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Based on the information you have provided, I would guess you are targeting .NET Core, which does not have a Property for Verb in ProcessStartInfo.